# SOQL AggregateResult Query throws error: System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0

Tags: apex, soql, map, aggregate, aggregateresult

**Background**

I have this Apex SOQL query:

```
    myMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT OpportunityLineItemId, 
                                        MIN(ScheduleDate) Starts
                                        FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule 
                                        WHERE OpportunityLineItemId IN :opportunityLineItemMap.keySet()
                                        AND ScheduleDate != NULL
                                        GROUP BY OpportunityLineItemId]);
```

Which throws this error:

> System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0

**Questions**

1. Why?
2. What am I doing wrong?
3. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to alias some field to `Id` in order for the `Map<Id, SObject>(List<SObject>)` constructor to work.

```
SELECT
    OpportunityLineItemId Id, 
    MIN(ScheduleDate) Starts
FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY OpportunityLineItemId
```

As your query is currently written, a given `AggregateResult` will only allow you to get three "fields":

- `expr0`
- `OpportujnityLineItemId`
- `Starts`